# NullPointerException after implementing an tournaments entity

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

## NullPointerException after implementing an tournaments entity

I am trying to create seed data for use on client side testing w/ angular

This the relationship between the entities,

Games Entity

- Games can only have 1 away team but team can have many away games
- Games can only have 1 home team but team can have many home games
- Games can only have 1 tournamnet but tournament can have many games

Games properties below, Games is not owning any of these relationships

```
    private Date date;
    
    private String location;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="home_team_id")
    private Team home;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="away_team_id")
    private Team away;
    
    @ManyToOne(optional = true)
    @JoinColumn(name="tournament_id")
    private Tournaments tournament;
```

Now Player,

- player can only have 1 stats and stats can only be assigned 1 player, player owns this relationship
- Player can only be part of 1 team and a team can have many, Team owns this relationship

Player entity below,

```
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "player", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    private PlayerStats stats;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name= "team_id")
    private Team team;
    
    private String name;
    
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private TeamRole position;
```

Now Team,

- Team is asigned 1 team stats and teamstats can only be assigned with 1 team, teams owns this relationship
- Team can have many players and players can only have 1 team, teams owns this relationship
- Team can have many homeGames but Games can only have one home team, same for teams awayGames, teams owns this relationship
- Team can have many tournaments and tournaments can have many teams, tournaments own this relationship
  Team entity below, *Note console references this entity, commented the line in which the console is referencing*

```
    private String name;
    
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "team", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    private TeamStats stats;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "team", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Player> players;
    
    @OneToMany( mappedBy = "home", cascade = CascadeType.ALL )
    private List<Games> homeGames;

    @OneToMany( mappedBy= "away", cascade = CascadeType.ALL )
    private List<Games> awayGames;
    
    //MANY TEAMS TO MANY 
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="numOfParticpants")
    private List<Tournaments> upcommingTournaments;
    
    public void addPlayer(Player player) {
        players.add(player);//console reference this line
        player.setTeam(this);
    }
    
    public void removePlayer(Player player) {
        players.remove(player);
        player.setTeam(null);
    }
    
    public void addHomeGame(Games game) {
        homeGames.add(game);
        game.setHome(this);
    }
    public void removeHomeGame(Games game) {
        homeGames.remove(game);
        game.setHome(null);
    }
    public void addAwayGame(Games game) {
        awayGames.add(game);
        game.setAway(this);
    }
    public void removeAwayGame(Games game) {
        awayGames.remove(game);
        game.setAway(null);
    }
```

Now all my implementations worked perfectly fine before implementing the tournaments entity and its relationships with the other entities so my, `loadPlayerTeamData()` & `loadGamesData()` worked perfectly fine until I implemented `loadTournamentsData()` and the tournaments entity and its relationships

- Tournament can have many participants(Team) and a Team can participate in many tournaments
- Tournament can have many games but a game can only be assigned to one tournament, IF a game is for a tournament otherwise the game will null value if game is just exhibition

Tournament owns all these relationships

Tournament entity

```
    private String name;
    
    private Date scheduledDate;
    
    //MANY TOURNAMENTS TO MANY TEAMS
    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.MERGE})
    @JoinTable(
            name= "tournament_participants",
            joinColumns= @JoinColumn(name = "team_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns= @JoinColumn(name="tournament_id")
        )
    private List <Team> numOfParticpants;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="tournament", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List <Games> totalGames;
    
    private String location;
    
    private TournamentSize tournamentSize;

    public void addParticipant(Team team) {
        this.numOfParticpants.add(team);
        team.getUpcommingTournaments().add(this);
    }
    
    public void removeParticipant(Team team) {  
        this.numOfParticpants.remove(team);
        team.getUpcommingTournaments().remove(this);
    }
    public void addGame(Games game) {
        this.totalGames.add(game);
        game.setTournament(this);
    }
    public void removeGame(Games game) {
        this.totalGames.remove(game);
        game.setTournament(null);
    }
```

Again, everything was working fine before implementing tournaments and its relationships, no null pointer exception, no errors at all, my databases were being populated

My question is, **WHAT WENT WRONG LOL**, i get a nullPointException within my `loadPlayerTeamDataSeed()` when before implementing tournaments this wasnt a issue.

Console,

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.util.List.add(Object)" because "this.players" is null
    at com.unknown.server.model.Team.addPlayer(Team.java:105) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.unknown.server.dataseed.DataSeed.loadPlayerTeamData(DataSeed.java:88) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.unknown.server.dataseed.DataSeed.run(DataSeed.java:55) ~[classes/:na]
```

Seeding implementation below,

```
    private void loadPlayerTeamData() {
        List<Team> teamList = teamService.getAllTeams().get();
        
        Team team = new Team();
        
        while(teamList.size() < 50) {
            //set player name and position
            Player player = new Player();
            player.setName(faker.name().fullName());
            player.setPosition(TeamRole.randomRole());
            
            //set playerStats
            PlayerStats playerStats = new PlayerStats(
                    player, 
                    faker.number().numberBetween(1, 20),
                    faker.number().numberBetween(1, 20),
                    faker.number().numberBetween(1, 20),
                    faker.number().numberBetween(2, 40),
                    faker.number().numberBetween(1, 20),
                    faker.number().numberBetween(1, 20));
            
            player.setStats(playerStats);
            
            //add player to team
            team.addPlayer(player); //This what the console is refering to
            if(team.getPlayers().size() >= 10) {
                //Set team and teamStats data
                int assists = 0, blocks = 0, 
                    points = 0, rebounds = 0, 
                    steals = 0, turnovers = 0;
                for(Player p: team.getPlayers()) {
                    assists =assists+p.getStats().getAssist();
                    blocks= blocks+p.getStats().getBlocks();
                    points= points+p.getStats().getPoints();
                    rebounds= rebounds+p.getStats().getRebounds();
                    steals= steals+p.getStats().getRebounds();
                    turnovers= turnovers+p.getStats().getTurnovers();
                }
                TeamStats teamStats = new TeamStats(
                        rebounds/team.getPlayers().size(), 
                        assists/team.getPlayers().size(), 
                        blocks/team.getPlayers().size(), 
                        points/team.getPlayers().size(), 
                        steals/team.getPlayers().size(), 
                        turnovers/team.getPlayers().size());
                team.setName(faker.pokemon().name());
                team.setStats(teamStats);
                
                teamService.addTeam(team);
                
                team = new Team();
                teamList = teamService.getAllTeams().get();
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    //3 away games and 3 home games per team 
    private void loadGamesData() {
        List<Games> games = new ArrayList<Games>();
            
        List<Team> teams = teamService.getAllTeams().get();
            
        while(teams.size() > 1) {
            Team t = teams.get(0);
            teams.remove(0);
            while(t.getHomeGames().size() < 2) {
                int a = teams.size() == 2 ? faker.number().numberBetween(teams.size()/2, teams.size()-1) : faker.number().numberBetween(0, teams.size()-1);
                
                Date d = faker.date().future(1, TimeUnit.DAYS);
                String location = faker.address().fullAddress();
                
                Team opp = teams.get(a);
                
                Games game = new Games(d, location, t, opp, null);
                t.addHomeGame(game);
                opp.addAwayGame(game);
                games.add(game);
            }
            while(t.getAwayGames().size() < 2) {
                int a = teams.size() == 2 ? faker.number().numberBetween(0, teams.size()/2) : faker.number().numberBetween(0, teams.size()-1);
                
                Date d = faker.date().future(1, TimeUnit.DAYS);
                String location = faker.address().fullAddress();
                
                Team opp = teams.get(a);
                
                Games game = new Games(d, location, opp, t, null);
                t.addAwayGame(game);
                opp.addHomeGame(game);
                games.add(game);
            }
        }
            
        for(Games g: games) {
            gamesService.addGame(g);
        }
    }
    
    private void loadTournamentsData() {
        List<Tournaments> tournies = new ArrayList<>();
        
        List<Team> teams = teamService.getAllTeams().get();
        
        List<Team> scheduled = new ArrayList<>();
        
        while(tournies.size() < 10){
            Tournaments tournie = new Tournaments();
            String location = faker.address().fullAddress();
            tournie.setName(faker.pokemon().name());
            tournie.setLocation(location);
            tournie.setScheduledDate(faker.date().future(50, TimeUnit.DAYS));
            
            //populate list of participants and add to tournament
            for(int i = 0; i < TournamentSize.fixedSize(TournamentSize.EIGHT); i++) {
                Team team = teams.get(faker.number().numberBetween(0, teams.size()-1));
                scheduled.add(team);
                teams.remove(team);
                tournie.addParticipant(team);
            }
            
            //create games
            int opp1 = 0, opp2 = scheduled.size()-1;
            while(opp1 < opp2) {
                Team home = scheduled.get(opp1);
                Team away = scheduled.get(opp2);
                
                Games game = new Games(
                        faker.date().future(52, TimeUnit.DAYS),
                        location,
                        home,
                        away,
                        null
                        );
                tournie.addGame(game);
                opp1++;
                opp2--;
            }
            tournies.add(tournie);
            scheduled.clear();
        }
        for(Tournaments t: tournies) {
            tournamentsService.addTournament(t);
        }
        
    }
```

**It's important to remember before implementing the tournaments entity and its classes this was not a issue**, should I use NoSQL instead of SQL, I know that would probably be best but SQL works for alot of my data except for tournaments it seems.

THank you to anyone who tries to help

Comment: You never assign a value to your lists: `private List<Player> players;` is initialized with `null` and you never set it to a different value.

Comment: Yes this makes sense actually, from both answers. So I need to set the list when I set the relationship as such                                                                                                   
`@OneToMany(mappedBy = "team", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)`
`private List<Player> players = new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: ***UPDATE***, I understand lol, power of contructors lol, I set my contructors to init entity lists

Answer (score 0):

In `loadPlayerTeamData()` you create a new Team `Team team = new Team();` and than you try to add a player on a not initialized `players` list